# JSON coordinates not showing with OpenLayers 3

Tags: openlayers-2, features, openlayers, json, markers

I hope you guys could help me. It has been several days since it tried and failed on populating my markers using a JSON method.

Please point out where I'm making a mistake. Below is my code:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
<style>
    .map {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>
<script src="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/build/ol.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<style>
    .map:-moz-full-screen {
        height: 100%;
    }
    .map:-webkit-full-screen {
        height: 100%;
    }
    .map:-ms-fullscreen {
        height: 100%;
    }
    .map:full-screen {
        height: 100%;
    }
    .ol-rotate {
        top: 3em;
    }
    .ol-popup {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: white;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2));
        filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2));
        padding: 15px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        border: 1px solid #cccccc;
        bottom: 12px;
        left: -50px;
    }
        .ol-popup:after, .ol-popup:before {
            top: 100%;
            border: solid transparent;
            content: " ";
            height: 0;
            width: 0;
            position: absolute;
            pointer-events: none;
        }
        .ol-popup:after {
            border-top-color: white;
            border-width: 10px;
            left: 48px;
            margin-left: -10px;
        }
        .ol-popup:before {
            border-top-color: #cccccc;
            border-width: 11px;
            left: 48px;
            margin-left: -11px;
        }
    .ol-popup-closer {
        text-decoration: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 2px;
        right: 8px;
    }
        .ol-popup-closer:after {
            content: "✖";
        }
</style>
<title>OpenLayers 3 example</title>
</head>
<body>
@*<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">
        <div id="map" class="map"></div>*@
@*</div>
    </div>*@
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12">
            <select id="layer-select" name="layer-select">
                <option value="Aerial">Aerial</option>
                <option value="AerialWithLabels">Aerial with labels</option>
                <option value="Road" selected>Road</option>
            </select>
            <div id="map" class="map"></div>
            <div id="no-download" class="alert alert-error" style="display: none">
                This example requires a browser that supports the
                <a href="http://caniuse.com/#feat=download">link download</a> attribute.
            </div>
            <a id="export-png" class="btn btn-info" download="map.png"><i class="icon-download"></i> Export PNG</a>
        </div>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span12">
                <div id="map" class="map">
                    <div id="popup" class="ol-popup">
                        <a href="#" id="popup-closer" class="ol-popup-closer"></a>
                        <div id="popup-content"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<script type="text/javascript"
/**
* Elements that make up the popup.
*/
var container = document.getElementById('popup');
var content = document.getElementById('popup-content');
var closer = document.getElementById('popup-closer');
/**
Add a click handler to hide the popup.
**/
closer.onclick = function () {
        container.style.display = 'none';
        closer.blur();
        return false;
    };
    /**
     * Create an overlay to anchor the popup to the map.
   */
    var overlay = new ol.Overlay({
        element: container
    });
    var count = 10;
    var features = []; //new Array(count);
    var e = 4500000;
    $('#filter').ready(function () {
        var FiltAddress = $('#FiltAddress').val();
        var FiltProject = $('#FiltProject').val();
        var FiltRegion = $('#FiltRegion').val();
        var FiltProvince = $('#FiltProvince').val();
        var FiltMunicipality = $('#FiltMunicipality').val();
        var FiltBarangay = $('#FiltBarangay').val();
        var FiltName = $('#FiltName').val();
        var url = "/Projects/GetZamboMarkers?FiltAddress=" + FiltAddress +
              "&FiltProject=" + FiltProject;
        var y = -1;
        $.getJSON(url, function (json1) {
            $.each(json1, function (key, data) {                  
                var coordinates = ol.proj.transform([data.Longitude, data.Latitude], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
                features[key] = new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Point(coordinates));
                alert(features);
            });
        })
        var source = new ol.source.Vector({
            features: features
        });
        var clusterSource = new ol.source.Cluster({
            distance: 40,
            source: source
        });
        var styleCache = {};
        var clusters = new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: clusterSource,
            style: function (feature, resolution) {
                var size = feature.get('features').length;
                var style = styleCache[size];
                if (!style) {
                    style = [new ol.style.Style({
                        image: new ol.style.Circle({
                            radius: 10,
                            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                                color: '#fff'
                            }),
                            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                                color: '#3399CC'
                            })
                        }),
                        text: new ol.style.Text({
                            text: size.toString(),
                            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                                color: '#fff'
                            })
                        })
                    })];
                    styleCache[size] = style;
                }
                return style;
            }
        });
        var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.MapQuest({ layer: 'osm' })
        });
        var raw = new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: source
        });
        var map = new ol.Map({
            layers: [raster, clusters],
            overlays: [overlay],
            //    renderer: exampleNS.getRendererFromQueryString(),
            target: 'map',
            view: new ol.View({
                center: [0, 0],
                zoom: 2
            }),
            controls: ol.control.defaults().extend([
             new ol.control.FullScreen(),

            ]),
        });
        /**
         * Add a click handler to the map to render the popup.
         */
        map.on('click', function (evt) {
            var coordinate = evt.coordinate;
            var hdms = ol.coordinate.toStringHDMS(ol.proj.transform(
                coordinate, 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326'));
            overlay.setPosition(coordinate);
            content.innerHTML = '<p>You clicked here:</p><code>' + coordinate +
                '</code>';
            container.style.display = 'block';
        });
        var exportPNGElement = document.getElementById('export-png');
        if ('download' in exportPNGElement) {
            exportPNGElement.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                map.once('postcompose', function (event) {
                    var canvas = event.context.canvas;
                    exportPNGElement.href = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
                });
                map.renderSync();
            }, false);
        } else {
            var info = document.getElementById('no-download');
            /**
            * display error message
            */
            info.style.display = '';
        }
    }) //javascript load
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please add the JSON response from call to /Projects/GetZamboMarkers ?

Comment: Heres a sample response: 
[{"BasicPackageId":1,"MetaPackageId":1,"Latitude":11.368,"Longitude":120.222,"Altitude":1,"GpsDateTimeStamp":"\/Date(1419834156000)\/","GetDateTaken":"\/Date(1419834164000)\/","Type":"1","FileName":"1","region_code":"11","prov_code":"1","city_code":"1","brgy_code":"1","sitio":"11","MetaCategoryId":1,"Cost":11,"Status":1,"Description":"eiffel","PicassaCollection":"1","PicassaSingle":"11","DerMandarValue":"1","DerManDarFunction":"1","DerManDarScript":"1","GeoEncode":"1"}]

Answer (score 1):

I have already resolved this.

heres my answer:

HTML:

OpenLayers 3 - LayerSwitcher

```
<style>
    html, body {
        height: 100%;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-size: small;
    }

    #map {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .popup {
        background: white;
        width: 250px;
        height: 200px;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }

    .closebtn {
        position: absolute;
        right: 4px;
    }

    #text {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 1em;
        left: 1em;
        width: 300px;
        z-index: 20000;
        border: solid 1px #999;
        background-color: rgba(227,233,238,.6);
        -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
        -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
        -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 4px;
        -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 4px;
        -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 4px;
        -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 4px;
        -moz-border-radius-topleft: 4px;
        -moz-border-radius-topright: 4px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
        border-top-left-radius: 4px;
        border-top-right-radius: 4px;
        text-align: center;
        height: auto;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .olControlAttribution {
        background-color: rgba(227,233,238,.6);
        -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
        -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
        -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 4px;
        -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 4px;
        -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 4px;
        -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 4px;
        -moz-border-radius-topleft: 4px;
        -moz-border-radius-topright: 4px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
        border-top-left-radius: 4px;
        border-top-right-radius: 4px;
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
```

Draw Points
    Draw Lines
    Draw Polygon

```
<script src="~/Scripts/bower_components/openlayers3/build/ol.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/ol_custom_src/ol3-layerswitcher.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/ol_custom/layerswitcher.js"></script>
```

@{  Layout = "~/Views/Shared/public/_layout.cshtml";}

JAVASCRIPT (layerswitcher.js)

var count = 10;
var features = [];// new Array(count);
var query = [];
var e = 4500000;

var map = null;

(function () {

```
map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Group({
            'title': 'Base maps',
            layers: [
                new ol.layer.Tile({
                    title: 'Stamen Toner',
                    type: 'base',
                    visible: false,
                    source: new ol.source.Stamen({
                        layer: 'toner'
                    })
                }),

                new ol.layer.Tile({
                    title: 'OSM',
                    type: 'base',
                    visible: true,
                    source: new ol.source.OSM()
                }),
                new ol.layer.Tile({
                    title: 'Satellite',
                    type: 'base',
                    visible: false,
                    source: new ol.source.MapQuest({ layer: 'sat' })
                }),


                  new ol.layer.Tile({
                      title: 'Google Map',
                      type: 'base',
                      visible: false,
                      source: new ol.source.MapQuest({ layer: 'sat' })
                  })


            ]
        }),
        new ol.layer.Group({
            title: 'Overlays',
            layers: [
                new ol.layer.Tile({
                    title: 'Countries',
                    source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
                        url: 'http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wms',
                        params: { 'LAYERS': 'ne:ne_10m_admin_1_states_provinces_lines_shp' },
                        serverType: 'geoserver'
                    })
                }),

                 new ol.layer.Tile({
                     title: 'Philippines',
                     source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
                         url: 'http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wms',
                         params: { 'LAYERS': 'ne:ne_10m_admin_1_states_provinces_lines_shp' },
                         serverType: 'geoserver'
                     })
                 }),



                 new ol.layer.Tile({
                     title: 'Streams',
                     source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
                         preload: Infinity,
                         url: 'http://felek.cns.umass.edu:8080/geoserver/wms',
                         serverType: 'geoserver',
                         params: {
                             'LAYERS': "Streams:Developed",
                             'TILED': true
                         }
                     })
                 }),



            ]
        })
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.transform([120, 12.96], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
        zoom: 6
    })
});

$("#filter").click(function () {

    var FiltAddress = $('#FiltAddress').val();

    var FiltProject = $('#FiltProject').val();

    var FiltRegion = $('#FiltRegion').val();

    var FiltProvince = $('#FiltProvince').val();

    var FiltMunicipality = $('#FiltMunicipality').val();

    var FiltBarangay = $('#FiltBarangay').val();

    var FiltName = $('#FiltName').val();

    var url = "/Projects/GetZamboMarkers?FiltAddress=" + FiltAddress +
          "&FiltProject=" + FiltProject;



    $.getJSON(url, function (json1) {

        $.each(json1, function (key, data) {

            features[key] = new ol.Feature({
                geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([data.Longitude, data.Latitude], 'EPSG:4326',
                'EPSG:3857')),
                name: [data.Description],
                population: 4000,
                rainfall: 500,

            });

        });



        var source = new ol.source.Vector({
            features: features
        });

        var clusterSource = new ol.source.Cluster({
            distance: 40,
            source: source
        });

        var styleCache = {};

        var clusters = new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: clusterSource,
            style: function (feature, resolution) {
                var size = feature.get('features').length;
                var style = styleCache[size];
                if (!style) {
                    style = [new ol.style.Style({
                        image: new ol.style.Circle({
                            radius: 10,
                            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                                color: '#fff'
                            }),
                            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                                color: '#3399CC'
                            })
                        }),
                        text: new ol.style.Text({
                            text: size.toString(),
                            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                                color: '#fff'
                            })
                        })
                    })];
                    styleCache[size] = style;
                }
                return style;
            }
        });

        map.addLayer(clusters);
    })

})


var layerSwitcher = new ol.control.LayerSwitcher({
    tipLabel: 'DSWD Layer Switcher' // Optional label for button
});

map.addControl(layerSwitcher);
```

})();